# Отключить комбинацию клавиш Ctrl + Win + D (создание виртуального рабочего стола)

Tags: windows-10, реестр, regedit

Поддержка микрасофтеров еще в 2019 году отвечала на подобный запрос созданием 16ричного мапа в реестре,но теперь лазейка не работает. Отсюда вопрос каким способом еще можно отключить столь неудобное сочетание, которое, при этом, часто прожимается в играх.
Ответ отключить все сочетания клавиш не принимается.

Comment: Это в каких таких играх используется Win клавиша оО?  Win - это OS, а не работа с софтом и очень нелогично использовать это сочетание в играх. Тем более, эту кнопку сейчас многие производители тех же клавиатур отрубают во время игр (игровой режим). Так что, тут вина не OS, а "умного" создателя вашей игрульки, который допустил такое сочетание клавиш в своей игре.

Comment: Дело не в том, что в игре используется win (это уже совсем было бы смешно), но так получается что все соседние клавиши используются, что и вызывает батхерт после очередного сворачивания во время игр. А лочить клавишу win во время игры решение не оптимальное (хотя и методов много), тк привык часто использовать win + tab для быстрого переключения в тех же играх. Вопрос стоит как отключить или почему нельзя)